# What is the rule for "difficult time" elision?

Tags: elision

> It is happening at a **difficult time.**

I notice it sounds "difficul time".

Comment: This is a phenomenon of how fast the speaker is speaking. With someone who is not speaking quickly, you would hear the /t/ at the end of *difficult* and the /t/ at the start of *time*.  It would not be in any way odd or strange to speak slowly enough that the two words are separate and distinct.

Comment: They'll be separate and distinct, but you still won't say two complete stops unless you are over enunciating for emphasis.  The separation between the words is the length of how long you hold the stop.  It's still a matter of starting one stop, holding, and then finishing with the second stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *exactly* "difficul" that you're hearing.  There is, in fact, a slight phonetic difference between "difficul time" and "difficult time".  Basically, you start making the /t/ sound, but you hold the occlusion for a moment before concluding it at the start of the next word.  Without holding this stop, there'd be no separation between the two words, and "Difficultime" would be the appropriate interpretation.

The rule is that when a word ends on a stop, and the next word starts with a stop, you don't say two different stops.  Instead, you should start the first stop, hold it, and then conclude with the second stop.  This rule holds true even when the two stops are different types, /t/ to /g/ for instance.  "Tight game" will have you shifting your tongue mid-stop and adding voice in order to start with a /t/ but end with a /g/.